# Can iOS device detect Eddystone beacon when app is killed/suspended?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, geofencing, eddystone

I need to write an app that calls a REST service each time it is near an Eddystone beacon.
My target is iOS 9 or greater and writing in Swift.

So far I have managed to have the app respond to advertisement from the beacon when the app is in foreground  and when the app is in background for a few hours.
Then after a few hours that the app is in background, nothing happens.

I suspect the app is killed by the OS or suspended.

The first thing I tried was geofencing with CLLocationManager and CLBeaconRegion.
But after googling around I gathered that this only works with iBeacon, and my beacon uses for sure the Eddystone protocol.

As per Apple docs, a geofencing on an iBeacon should "awake" the app even if the app has been killed (either by a human or by the OS).. can I have a similar behaviour with an Eddystone beacon?

I think not, but in this case I'd like a definitive answer :)

Thanks

BTW, this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

talks sometimes about Beacons and some other about iBeacons, so it's not super clear if this applies only to iBeacons or not. Given the format of the UUID I think it does, but..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iOS CoreLocation APIs to launch an app into the background on beacon detection when monitoring for a CLBeaconRegion object.  **This only works with iBeacon and not with Eddystone**, because CoreLocation only detects iBeacon.

To detect Eddystone on iOS, you must use CoreBluetooth APIs, which do not offer this feature.

A common approach to do what you want is to use a beacon that interleaves  both Eddystone and iBeacon.  Use the iBeacon for launching your app and Eddystone for further processing.

Comment: Can you point me to an official Apple doc that states clearly that only iBeacon can wake apps from sleeping/dead state? The above document is a little bit vague for non technical people, and I need one to show to a customer :)

Comment: Sorry, I am sure no such documentation exists.  (Unfortunately, you'll be hard pressed to find any reference to any Google technology like Eddystone n Apple docs -- they like to pretend it does not exist.) However, I can tell you I discussed this exact issue with Google's design engineers on the Eddystone project before it's release, and we agreed the solution described above is the way to get a background launch on iOS using Eddystone.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll take your word for it.